# Truncate binary number

Tags: c++, binary, bitwise-operators

I would like to truncate every digit after the first non zero digit in the binary representation of an integer. I also need this to be as simple as possible (no function or multiple lines of code).

In example:

```
// in c++
int int1=7,int2=12,int3=34;   //needs to work for any number
```

using some sort of operator (maybe bitwise combination?), I need these to give the following values

```
int1 -> 4
int2 -> 8
int3 -> 32
```

Truncating in binary was the only thing I could think of, so I am open to any ideas.

Thanks!

Comment: Every way I know to do this involves multiple lines of code. Are you sure you can't handle a function call wherever you are going to be using this?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I am doing a triple integration, so no. But I think I may look into storing the values I need beforehand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [pretty neat trick](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#RoundUpPowerOf2) can be used for that:

```
if ((v & (v - 1)) == 0) {
    return v;
}
v--;
v |= v >> 1;
v |= v >> 2;
v |= v >> 4;
v |= v >> 8;
v |= v >> 16;
v++;
v >>= 1;
return v;
```

The idea is to "`OR` in" all ones below the top one after decrementing the value, and then increment the value back at the end. I added a shift right at the end to the standard trick, because the original code was designed to find the smallest `2^n` greater than or equal to the given value.

**EDIT:** I also added a special case for `2^N`, which is [another trick from the same list](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#DetermineIfPowerOf2).

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/XHkTMa).

Comment: I think you need to adjust for the case of an exact power of 2. I got 16 running your code for input 32. Maybe keep the original value of v as old_v, and if the value of v after v++ is equal to old_v, don't do the final shift.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Thanks for the note, I added a work-around for this special case.

Comment: Thanks, I am not that good with bitwise operators, but I am assuming that this checks all possible cases, thus would require more checks for anything higher than 31 (right?). For my purpose, I need to assume that the maximum number is 2^15, so I am afraid that doing so would dramatically slow down the process, which I cannot afford (approximating an integral).

Comment: @user1888743 There are no additional checks that you would need to perform. This trick works for all values of v within the range, assuming that v is unsigned.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight How would you implement this in a `#define` statement in such a way that you could use it as a single value?

Comment: @user1888743 Why, wouldn't an inlineable C99 function work? Macro would be incredibly ugly...

Answer (score 3):

This function is from the book `Hacker's Delight`.

```
// greatest power of 2 less than or equal to n (floor pow2)

uint32_t flp2(uint32_t n)
{
    n |= n >> 1;
    n |= n >> 2;
    n |= n >> 4;
    n |= n >> 8;
    n |= n >> 16;
    return n - (n >> 1);
}
```

And I might as well post the related `clp2` function:

```
// least power of 2 greater than or equal to n (ceiling pow2)

uint32_t clp2(uint32_t n)
{
    n -= 1; 
    n |= n >> 1;
    n |= n >> 2;
    n |= n >> 4;
    n |= n >> 8;
    n |= n >> 16;
    return n + 1;
}
```